# VSCode Does Not Recognize Any Modules

Tags: python, git, visual-studio-code

Recently, my VSCode has just entirely stopped recognizing any and all modules. This started after one of my friends was helping me connect to git to push and pull updates to a .js file, and ever since then my VSCode seems to have handed me its resignation. We were doing some things in the terminal regarding node.js and git, but it was about two weeks ago by now so I don't remember exactly all of what we did.

**Error: **

- "import pandas as pd

  ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'"

The above occurs for any and every modules you can think of that was previously so easy for it to access.

**Solutions I've tried:**

- Uninstalling and reinstalling VSCode
- Trying different interpreters

  - Tried virtual environment? Yep. Global environment? Sure did. YOUR environment? Probably.
- Downloading libraries into terminal in VSCode itself? Requirements already satisfied :(

Has anyone else encountered this before? I've scoured through stackoverflow forums and it seems like most of the solutions involve setting up a .venv or changing interpreters. Not sure where else I can go from here.

Comment: Are you getting an error from IntelliSense when editing your code, or is the terminal prompting an error when you run the script

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem. try using IDLE. libraries should work in it, most likely your problem is in pip. perhaps the folder was cloned, and visual studio is being sent to another folder

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately not, still tells me there is no module named pandas, even though I SEE it when I run 'pip list'